# Which of the algebra isomorphisms hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Fix $m, n \ge 1$. Which of the algebra isomorphisms below hold?

1. $k\langle t_1, \dots, t_m\rangle \otimes_k k\langle s_1, \dots, s_n\rangle \cong k\langle t_1, \dots, t_m, s_1, \dots, s_n\rangle$
2. $k[ t_1, \dots, t_m] \otimes_k k[ s_1, \dots, s_n] \cong k[ t_1, \dots, t_m, s_1, \dots, s_n]$

Comment: The square brackets mean commutative polynomials I assume. What do the angle brackets refer to?

Comment: Also, is k a field and are the t_i and s_i all indeterminates?

Comment: The second isomorphism holds, the first is false. See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400684/tensor-product-and-direct-product-of-algebra-presentations).